# C++ error: no matching function for call to 'Car::Car()'

Tags: c++, function, encapsulation

I started learning C++ in my free time and came across an error while learning Encapsulation. Here is the code (this is a slight modification to what is explained at W3Schools):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Car {                          // The class
    private:                         // Access specifier to prevent outsiders from viewing (ENCAPSULATION)
        int theMSRP;                // Private attribute of the car (we don't want random person seeing car price)
    public:
        string brand;               // Attribute
        string model;               // Attribute
        int year;                   // Attribute
        Car(string x, string y, int z){ // Constructor with parameters
            brand = x;
            model = y;
            year = z;
        }
        // Private access specifier SETTER
        void setMSRP(int m){
            theMSRP = m;
        }
        // Private access specifier GETTER
        int getMSRP(){
            return theMSRP;
            }
};

int main(){
    // Create Car objects and call the constructor with different values
    Car myObjMSRP;
    myObjMSRP.setMSRP(100000);
    Car carObj1("Mercedes Benz", "G-Wagon", 2021);

    // Print the values
    cout << carObj1.brand << " " << carObj1.model << " " << carObj1.year << " \n";
    cout << myObjMSRP.getMSRP();
    return 0;
}
```

The error message returns error: no matching function for call to 'Car::Car()'. I am somewhat confused since the other object works with the Car class, but myObjMSRP object does not?

Thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: As an aside from my answer below. It's bad form to leave a member variable uninitialized when the constructor returns.  You should at least initialize `theMSRP` to zero if your constructor doesn't take a parameter for it to be explicitly set.

Comment: [Documentation page that covers the Member Initializer List](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor)

Comment: It's better if you move initialize when passing `std::string` as value.

Comment: Thanks for all of your comments everyone - yes, I will review the member initializer list!

Comment: Please accept the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the default constructor. Put this:

```
Car () {
   make = "";
   model = "";
   year = "";
   std::cout << "Hell got loose!!!";
}
```

You will be calling it from this line

```
Car myObjMSRP;
```

Or you could have

```
Car myObjMSRP ("Nissan", "Q5", 2011);
```

Although one suggestion, learn about initializer lists on constructors:

```
Car (string x, string y, string z) : make(x), model(y), year(z) {
}
```

is more eficiant than your way

Comment: Thanks a lot, I saw the link for initializer lists on constructors. I plan to take a look at it later tonight after work. I know it's a dumb question, but would you mind explaining why your way is more efficient than my way? Coming from Python, I see it as more of a "one liner trick" vs having it broken down line by line. Am I accurate or are there other benefits in terms of processing, memory, etc? Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
Car myObjMSRP;
```

You need to pass constructor params:

```
Car myObjMSRP("Tesla", "Roadster", 2022);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the clear explanation - can't believe I missed that!